# Where should I host php file for ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a very simple request.  I am trying to make a call using jQuery to a php file so that the file's response will be put into a "div".  I know there are other posts but for some reason none of them seem to be working for me.

Here is my code:

**gettable.php**

```
<?php
    echo "<p>Great-Success</p>";
?>
```

**sequencingfile.html**

```
jQuery("#tableHolder").load("/path/to/php-file/gettable.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
                    alert(response);
                    alert(status);
                    alert(xhr);
                  if (status == "error") {
                      console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                  }
                });
```

**Notes**

- The contents of the div changes to this:

  Great-Success

  "; ?>
- The html code is run after you click a button
- The div which I am trying to load the echo from the php call has id "tableHolder".
- I am running this on the firefox, it doesn't work on chrome at all.
- The response is the actual contents of the php file itself.
- The status is "success".
- The xhr is "[object Object]"
- Eventually I am trying to call the php file to query from a mysql database to create a table(if you know of a better and more efficient way of doing this please let me know), but for now all I want is the echo of the php call to come back and be put into the div as it should.
- The file is set locally
- The computer is linux
- That's all the detail I can think of, please let me know if you need any more details

**EDIT**

Alright I have set up an apache server and changed the link to `http://127.0.0.1/gettable.php` and it still doesn't work.  When I type that url into firefox or chrome it works, but not when I run the html file.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a webserver ?

Comment: The reason is you are not running it on any server, so php code are not able to compile. Install wamp/zamp and run your file on localhost.

Comment: no it is not on a webserver, it is just on a random folder on the computer like the desktop folder or documents or downloads.  Should I put the php or the html in a different folder?

Comment: @amun25: PHP can only run via a web server.  It's not like an HTML file that you can just open from your computer.  You can upload to one, or you can run one on your local machine with wampserver, xampp, etc.

Comment: It needs to be on a webserver.  It doesn't work like HTML where you can just place the file where ever and have it run correctly.  Download and install WAMP, then run WAMP and place your code in the WWW directory.  (if you are on windows, if not - look into LAMP).  It stands for Windows/Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.  Apache will be your webserver.  It is easier to install WAMP than Apache and PHP separately (IMHO).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work like HTML is that the HTML is interpreted by the browser, but it doesn't understand PHP. The PHP script must be executed and *its output* must be sent to the browser. Now, you don't need a webserver to execute a PHP file, but you need it to make it (or rather its output) available via an URL. If you have PHP 5.4, you can make use of its [internal webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), but only for development purposes. Ajax calls are normal HTTP requests, so you don't have to do anything special with those files.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be on a webserver. It doesn't work like HTML where you can just place the file where ever and have it run correctly. Download and install WAMP, then run WAMP and place your code in the WWW directory. (if you are on windows, if not - look into LAMP). It stands for Windows/Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP. Apache will be your webserver.  There are tons of installation guides online.  I am not sure which one will work best for you.

If you have a file called `test.php` in that folder... you will just go to `localhost/test.php` or `127.0.0.1/test.php`

**Sorry for the Wamp referral** I just saw that you are on *linux*.